# Get last few query results in SQL

Tags: sql, caching

I frequently do a static analysis of SQL databases, during which I have the luxury of nobody being able to change the data except me.

However, I have not found a way to 'tell' this to SQL in order to prevent running the same query multiple times.

Here is what I would like to do, first I start with a complicated query that has a very small output.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYPROPERTY = 1234
```

Then I run a simple query from the same window (Mostly using SQL server studio if that is relevant)

```
SELECT 1
```

Now I suddenly realize that I forgot to save the results from my first complicated (slow) query.

As I know the underlying data did not change (or even if it did) I would like to look one step back and simply get the result. However at the moment I don't know any trick to do this and I have to run the entire query again.

So the question summary is: How can I (automatically store/)get the results from recently executed queries.

I am particulary interested in simple select queries, and would be happy to allocate say 100MB memory for automated result storage. Would prefer a solution that works in SQL server studio with T-SQL, but other SQL solutions are also welcome.

---

**EDIT:** I am not looking for a way to manually prevent this from happening. In the cases where I can anticipate the problem it will not happen.

Comment: Though I am not sure whether it does what I describe, I may be looking for `RESULT_CACHE_MODE` for sql server http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/query-result-cache-11gr1.php

Comment: FWIW, SQL Server does a fairly decent job caching queries, and it might be clever enough to realize nobody's changed anything. Are you sure that running the entire query again is such a bad thing? Perhaps the best solution is no solution.

Comment: @catfood I have tried it many times, but actually I never notice a significant improvement in execution time if I run the same query twice.

Comment: There's hardly a way to do it for ANY query - it will be too performance-heavy. You can write a separate piece of software to run these analytic queries that will cache the results; or, if the query differs only in specific values, you can wrap it into a stored procedure that will handle the caching logic.

Comment: Well judging from the answers it seems possible as some systems can do it. Hopefully something exits for sql server as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done in Microsoft SQL Server. SQL Server does not cache results, instead it caches data pages that were accessed by your query. This should make your query go a lot faster the second time around so it won't be as painful to re-run it.

In other databases, such as Oracle and MySQL, they do have a query caching mechanism that will allow you to retrieve the results directly the second time around.

Answer (score 2):

I run into this frequently, I often just throw the results of longer-running queries into a temp table:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #results1
FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYPROPERTY = 1234
SELECT *
FROM #results1
```

If the query is very long-running I might use a 'real' table.  It's a good way to save on re-run time.

Downside is that it adds to your query.

You can also send query results to a file in SSMS, info on formatting the output is here: [SSMS Results to File](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2b4301a8-d7fd-46b3-9c60-e1f32c1d21d1/ssms-results-to-file)

Comment: Is there a way to automate this, or something similar?

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to cache results and display them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to run each query in its own SSMS window, the results will stay there until you close it, or run out of memory - besides that, I am not sure there is a way to accomplish what you want.

Once you close the SSMS window, I don't believe there is a way to get back 'cached' results.

Comment: So far this best answers my question, but I guess you can understand that I won't select it yet!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a technical answer to your question.  Having written queries and looking at results for many years, I am in the habit of saving the results in Excel, regardless of the database/query tool I'm using.

The format in Excel is rather methodical:

1. Each worksheet has the date.  (Called something like "1 Jul".)
2. Each spreadsheet contains one month.  (Typically with the month name like "work-201307".)
3. In the "B" column I copy and paste the query.
4. Underneath, in the "C" column, I copy and paste the results.
5. The next query starts a few lines after, one after the other.

I put the queries in the "B" column, so I can go to the "A" column and use  to get to the first row.  I put the results in the "C" column, so I can go to the "B" column and use  to move between queries.

I mostly do this so I can go back and see the work I did many months ago.  For instance, someone sends an email from February and says "do this again".  I can go back to the February spreadsheet, go to the day it was created, and see what I was doing at that time.

In your question, though, I realize that I now instinctively solve this problem, because the "right click on the grid, copy with column headers, alt-tab to excel, alt-V" is a behavior that I comes quite naturally.

Comment: Honestly, this answer shocked me! Giving it a second thought I guess that it is indeed a solution with some benefits (easily applied to multiple programs). However, as I already have the queries themselved managed quite well and am am mostly looking for more efficiency, I guess the cost of doing this manually will not outweigh the benefit for me. -- Thanks for your answer though, I hope it can help others.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin . . . I can add that I haven't found anything in SSMS or SQL Server that can address this problem.  You can't put a trigger on a `SELECT`.  You can't specify the output in SSMS to two places.  I'm not aware of an ability to log results.  You might be able to custom code an extension or find an ODBC driver that does such logging.  (Because I use different databases, a database-specific solution is not so helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest you to run each query into a script with a counter (stored in a table) increased each time the query is executed (i.e. i++) and storing each query in a Temp Table called "tmpTable" + i, but it sounds very complicated to manage. Am I right?

Then I googled and I've found this Tool Pack: I didn't try it but you could take a look:

http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features

Hope it helps.

EDIT: added the folliwing link. There's the option to output as XML file and they mention **SQL Server Integration Services** as a possible solution too.
http://michaeljswart.com/2012/03/sending-query-results-to-others/#method5

SECOND EDIT: There's this DBMS-Independent tool too, it sounds interesting:

http://www.sql-workbench.net/

Comment: I have read the features of smsstoolspack, but I cannot find anything about storing results (only about storing the queries themselves). The second one is a bit harder to read, but looks promising at first sight.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin There's this DBMS-Independent tool too,it sounds interesting: http://www.sql-workbench.net/

Comment: Looks like SQL workbench may have what I need. My main concern is, do you still (automatically) see the results of each query that you use wbexport on?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I never used SQL workbench... so I don't know. I found it googling around.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure this is what you want. Anyway check my answer

In sql server management studio you can open multiple tabs for executing queries. Open new tab for each query, then the result of executed queries will be available under that tab.

After executing one query in a tab dont use that tab for new query, open new tab for that job.

Comment: I am aware of the option not to overwrite the previous result. But still it happens sometimes and I am hoping to find a way to reduce the damage in those cases. (Also I think the navigation is horrible when you have more than about 5 tabs open) Have edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin-  you need to store maximum 2 or 3 results right?

Comment: Well more would be nicer, but even if I could always just go back 2 or 3 steps that would be a great step forward. So suppose I run 20 queries (mostly quick, but some turn out to be slow), and after running number 20 I suddenly realize that I actually needed number 19 (which takes quite a while to run).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using some kind of offline SQL client such as Excel?  Specifically, Excel will retrieve the results into the spread sheet (using the Data ribbon/menus) where they are stored pretty much permanently as results.  It will prompt you to refresh when necessary or you can do it on demand.

Your question as to whether it can be done in T/SQL or other databases depends on the database and results cache and even then they are options that the query processor can use not guarantees to the individual query.

Comment: I will look into Excel a bit. Do you find it to work comfortably and does it have autocomplete for example? About the second part of your answer, it is not really clear to me. What does it depend on, could you give an example perhaps?